# get updated value with firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a doc in a collection and if it doesn't exist I create a new one, I would like to know if there is any way to get `userData` even if it doesn't exist (so to assign it the new one I have created) or I need to take it with

```
     firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(ID);
```

again

```
    const userRef = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(ID);

  const user = await userRef.get();

  if (!user.exists) {
    userRef.set(userSchema);
  }


 const userData = user.data();
```

Comment: What error do you get? Also can you share your entire code? We see that you use `await` but we don't see where you declare the function `async`.

Comment: yeah this is inside an async function, the problem is that userData it's undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where the user data is coming from but let's have a test user as follows:

```
const userData = {
  name: "TestUser",
  uid: "1234",
  verified: true
}
```

Then here goes the function you need:

```
async function addUserToDatabase(userData) {
  //Document Reference
  const userDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userData.uid)
  //Checking if document exists
  if ((await userDocRef.get()).exists) {
    return "User document already exists!"
  }
  //Document does not exists so create one
  await userDocRef.set(userData)
  return
}
```

Comment: If you check my example, userData comes from firebase